# Remove space between menu icon and title

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view, android-resources

In the image below, how can I remove the space between the icon and the title of the item in the menu?

[image: Icon and menu item title image]

#### activity_main_drawer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app"
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:title="Logout" />
</menu>
```

#### styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.LoginButton" />
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

Comment: please post the code for what you have tried

Comment: Done. I am using AppCompat styles.

Comment: the answer is here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45138675/how-to-reduce-the-space-between-icon-and-home-up-key-in-custom-action-bar-in-and

Answer (score 1):

You can play with those values overriding [these](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/res/values/dimens.xml#L29) values in your **dimens.xml**:

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_padding" tools:override="true">10dp</dimen>
```

Though, it is not desirable to break material design guidelines.