# how to reduce the space between icon and home up key in custom action bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I'm using custom action bar in AppCompatActivity. I give the my code below as well as the pitcher. i tried all solution available in stack over flow. But till i can't fix this issue.please assist me.

**action_toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
style="@style/toolBarTheme"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/appLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvToolbarTitle"
        style="@style/textViewTheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/appLogo"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/appLogo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `toolbar` property for this

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

**like this use in toolbar**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `Toolbar` then add the following line in `Toolbar` in `xml`

```
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

**Update:**

You mean you want toolbar like Whatsapp. but it's not done by using **App-compat Support Library Toolbar** you have to use Custom Action Bar.

You can get the following result as shown in the Picture below

[image]

by using following code.

**activity.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_chats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
            <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**custom_toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
>
<!-- android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" will cause this Custom View to make ripple effect -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/conversation_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/conversation_contact_photo"
            android:layout_width="35.0dip"
            android:layout_height="35.0dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/conversation_image"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="2.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="0.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="0.0dip" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_title_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="shanraisshan"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_title_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="last seen 1 hour ago"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="12sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**`YourActivity.java`**

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_chats);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("Toolbar","Clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, tried this. see my code. To using this my Main Activity working correctly. But new activity its not working

Comment: very sorry @Mehul now only i saw your ans. but its not working. but above Ans working fine, i go for that. Thankyou

Comment: There seem to be a padding around the vector icon preventing any further reduction in space. Any way of reducing that padding?