# How to reduce gap between text and Hamburger icon on toolbar

Tags: java, android

[image: My Image]I am using default toolbar design inside Appbar layout in XML.

[Remove space between menu icon and title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42889792/remove-space-between-menu-icon-and-title)

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"`enter code here`
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/toolbarColor"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="@dimen/_1sdp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: You will have to create a custom toolbar

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to reply but it can help someone, currently by using androidx toolbar check the code below:

```
       <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
           ...
           app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
           app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
           app:titleMarginStart="0dp"/>
```

Just add these 3 lines

Answer (score 0):

Add these 2 lines ...

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            ...
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            ... 
         />
```

Comment: this is for remove gap of start side... but i want to reduce space between Hamburger Icon and Text. @Ferran

Comment: `app:contentInsetStart` and `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation` are for space between Hamburger Icon and Text. Try to put `contentInsetStart` to `100dp`, so, you can see the difference.